# How to avoid duplicate calls in PHP-built RestAPI?

Tags: php, mysql, api, rest, unique-key

I have a PHP script acting as Rest API for mobile app. It provides API method for creating order. Orders in DB have special column to keep order number. So simplified method for creating order looks like this:

```
function place_order($data) {
  $order_number = $db->getOne('SELECT MAX(order_number) FROM orders');
  $order_number++;
  $db->query('INSERT INTO order(order_number, data) VALUES(?,?)', 
    array($order_number, $data));
}
```

What sometimes happens is, that we end up with 2, sometimes 3 or very rarely 4 identical orders in DB with identical order_number. I suspect that mobile app due to some unknown reason creates more parallel requests which are then processed on server concurrently at the same time.

That mobile app shouldn't make these parallel requests is another story. But what I am trying to solve is server-side where it should never create orders with duplicate number and better - it should not allow multiple requests from specific IP for some time (few seconds should be enough).

But how to implement it ? If these requests are all parallel and technically few miliseconds apart, before script runs some logic to save user's IP to some storage, it other requests are already running and they check, that there is no other similar request running and proceed with creating duplicate order.
I know I could solve it by using UNIQUE KEY in database on order_number column. But I am wondering if I can solve it just on PHP side.
Thanks for any hints or tips.

Comment: Does an auto-increment key solve the problem?

Comment: Make `order_number` an auto incremented key. Also make it primary key

Comment: @NigelRen I use auto-increment for ID column. But order_number is not simple auto incremented column, but rather it is generated by using parts of date. But I simplified it for a sake of straight-forward question.